# Add a custom background image as my uiwebview starts to load (using Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

**Technologies:** XCode6, iOS 8.2, Swift

My web view takes a few seconds to fully load and I wanted to add a background image while users were waiting. I can easily change the color of the background, but what is the best way to add a background image?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false;
    openLoadingPopup()
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
    if browserHistory.count < 1 {
        backButton.enabled = false
    }
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        . networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    closeLoadingPopup()
    if cacheURL {
        ++browserHistoryIndex
        browserHistory.insert(webView.request!.URL, atIndex:   
        browserHistoryIndex)
        backButton.enabled = browserHistoryIndex != 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a `UIImageView` that covers the `UIWebView` while it is loading. Once the `webViewDidFinishLoad` is called, you can hide the image view.

To make it less jarring, you could quickly fade the image view in and out.

Comment: here is another way that I find as well:  let imageName = "image.png"
        self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: imageName)!)